# Does using a case statement in an update in the presence of a where clause make it less efficient?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

Query 1

```
update foo set 
  status = 1, 
  bar = 1 
where status = 0 and item_id in ("itemId1", "itemId2");
```

Query 2

```
update foo set 
  status = 1, 
  bar = case item_id 
    when "itemId1" then 4 
    when "itemId2" then 5 
  end 
where status = 0 and item_id in ("itemId1", "itemId2");
```

Logically, the two queries are doing different things. But I am adding a new feature which needs some conditional update logic and am evaluating if there will be any performance regression.

Are the two queries above equivalent in terms of performance? Note, the `CASE` statement will always be a subset of item_ids that were filtered for in the `WHERE` clause.
So MySQL shouldn't have to load any "extra" data, correct?

The only thing I can think of is that the raw size of the query string would be larger.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I will remove it

Comment: Wouldn't it be quicker (and more accurate) just to test this for yourself?

Comment: I would write each of your Queries as _two_ separate, simple `UPDATEs` for one item_id each.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little less efficient since it has to compare `item_id` to each string to determine what value to assign to `bar`.

But the efficiency of processing the `WHERE` clause should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

All columns of a given row are stored together on a page, so when doing an UPDATE once the page is loaded for some columns, the others come along for free. Unless the columns are large TEXT/BLOB content stored on overflow pages, they will be loaded with the row.

The cost of the query is mostly proportional to the number of rows it needs to examine, and that's driven by the conditions in the WHERE clause and whether the search uses an index to examine only the rows that will be updated.

Optimizing the length of the query string is *really* in the realm of micro-optimizations. I'm not saying it can never be important, but if it is, you should be measuring it yourself.